# MVC sql table data to html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, model-view-controller

Hi guys i am new to mvc i am trying to get the sql table details to html table for that what i done is i have created a controller and model and view i also created sql table with fields of voucher number and amount. here is how i created the controller here i have referenced the model modeldemo

```
<HttpGet>
        Function getVoucherDetails() As JsonResult
            Return Json(New ModelDemo().getVoucherDetails(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
        End Function
```

the model demo code consists of sql connection

```
Public Function getVoucherDetails() As List(Of Hashtable)
        Dim listCharts As List(Of Hashtable) = New List(Of Hashtable)
        Dim arrayCharts As Hashtable
        Try
            Dim conn = New SqlConnection(connStringLocal)
            conn.Open()
            Using query = New SqlCommand("SELECT vchNum,totalAmount FROM BillHeader", conn)
                Using resultSet = query.ExecuteReader
                    If resultSet.HasRows Then
                        While resultSet.Read()
                            arrayCharts = New Hashtable
                            arrayCharts.Add("vchNum", resultSet("vchNum"))
                            arrayCharts.Add("totalAmount", resultSet("totalAmount"))
                            listCharts.Add(arrayCharts)
                        End While
                    End If
                    resultSet.Close()
                    'resultSet = Nothing
                End Using
            End Using
            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            arrayCharts = New Hashtable
            arrayCharts.Add("error", ex.ToString)
            arrayCharts.Add("message", ex.Message)
            listCharts.Add(arrayCharts)
        End Try
        Return listCharts
    End Function

<table id="voucherTable">
         <thead><tr> vchNum </tr><tr>Total Amount</tr></thead>
         <tbody>
         </tbody>
     </table>
```

the document.load function consists of

```
$.post("@Url.Content("~")Home/SaveBill",$('#form1').serializeArray(),function(data){
                    console.log(data)


                    if (data.status == "success") {
                        alert(data.message)

                        $("# voucherTable >tbody").append('<tr><td><input name="vchNum"></td><td><input name="totalAmount"></td></tr>')
                    }

                    else {
                        alert("Error")
                        console.error(data.message)
                    }
                });
```

and index html consists of

```
<table id="voucherTable">
         <thead><tr> vchNum </tr><tr>Total Amount</tr></thead>
         <tbody>
         </tbody>
     </table>
```

and this is how i tried can anyone help

Comment: i am wrong in script how do i get the details to html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have space between `#voucherTable`  and  Just try  `$("#voucherTable tbody").append`